# Langchain cookbook TypeError

Tags: py-langchain

For some reason when I run the code below (which [can be found in the LangChain docs](https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/cookbook/retrieval)) I get the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'str'`

```
chain = (
    {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | prompt
    | model
    | StrOutputParser()
)
```

What might I be doing wrong? I have tried with different LangChain versions and haven't been able to make it work. The Python version I use (venv) is 3.10.12.

Answer (score 0):

What type does your prompt have?
I guess you are trying to feed the prompt as a `string` while it should be a `PromptTemplate`

```
prompt = "somestring..."
```

this will not work, you have to do:

```
template = "somestring..."
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
```

you will have to import the `ChatPromptTemplate` from `langchain_core.prompts`